# How to open dropdown when i have checkbox checked using jquery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

We have to checkbox checked then after checked checkbox reloads the page and open dropdown but not the open drop-down.
check my site https://vidyutbazar.com/bazardirectory/

**code**

```
  jQuery('#seller_id_filter').click(function() {
  if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true){
  jQuery("#main_cat_7").removeClass("collapsed");
  jQuery("#main_cat_7").css("aria-expanded", "true !important");
  jQuery("#collapse7").css("display", "block !important");
  jQuery("#collapse7").css("aria-expanded", "true !important");
  }
  else if(jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false){
  jQuery('#collapse7').css('display','none !important');
  }
  });
```

Please give me solution?

Comment: you should really consider using `$` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: you can use simulate js. refer link https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js

Comment: Your use of important scares me